# Cannot Find CSS Class For A Custom Block

Tags: blocks, theming

Hello due to much help from here in the past im starting to theme whatever part of my drupal site that i like. Its great. Ive ran into a a strange one though. I have created a custom block (block 130). You can see it on top of my site

BBC Live Olympics | Add Olympic Comment | Football Livescore | OLB Olympics
http://onlinebanter.com/latest

For some reason it doesnt have any div class Im trying to change the p bit.

Ive tried various things but still cant seem to find this blovk. Does anyine have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: durrr the p class was in the block itself. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a class, but you do have an ID so you can use:

```
#primary p {color:red;}
```

**Note:** there is also a nice module call block class (http://drupal.org/project/block_class) that you can use